# OpenTelemetry Counter in Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel, metrics, open-telemetry

I'm trying to add a simple OTEL counter in Laravel app and export it to otel-collector which then should export it to Prometheus.

When I was using AGGREGATION_TEMPORALITY_CUMULATIVE, I ran into the fact that the counter is being reset for each HTTP request made to the app. As far as I understood, the cumulative temporality is strongly depends on start timestamp of the meter which is reset on each request to the app since meter is created in request handler.

On the other hand, counter with AGGREGATION_TEMPORALITY_DELTA is not exported by otel-collector's exporter to Prometheus.

Is it possible to get telemetry counter work in Laravel/otel-collector/Prometheus combination?

My current versions of OTEL are:

- open-telemetry/opentelemetry - 0.0.14
- open-telemetry/sdk-contrib - 0.0.14
- otel-collector - latest docker image

Answer (score 0):

Checked the changes in the branch of https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pull/9006 . The version there works fine with AGGREGATION_TEMPORALITY_DELTA counter. So just need to wait when that issue is closed

Answer (score 0):

@MikeJc, I believe this issue is closed now; do you need anything else?  If so, please feel free to open an issue in https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-php/issues